# Поворот камерой для Android в Unity3d

Tags: unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как я могу сделать поворот камерой в трехмерном пространстве для Android? (Unity 2023)

Comment: Теперь вставьте этот же вопрос в поисковик

Comment: Там нет этого,,

Comment: Это не поисковик, это строка поиска. [Вот что](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pM6B.png) я имел ввиду.

Comment: мне нужно это для android

Comment: Для поворота объектов платформа не имеет разницы.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите осуществлять поворт камеры для имитации дополненной реальности, используйте данные с датчиков, напримаер с гироскопа.

```
//Вектор, представляющий глобальное направление вверх (Обратный вектору гравитации)
//В координатах телефона
Vector3 localDown = Quaternion.Inverse(Input.gyro.attitude) * Vector3.down;

// Насколько отклоняется вектор гравитации влево и вправо
float rollDegrees = Mathf.Asin(localDown.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

// Насколько отклоняется вектор гравитации вперёд и назад
float pitchDegrees = Mathf.Atan2(localDown.y, localDown.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
```